# Use variable in Firestore limit

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to be able to use a variable (`page`) in the limit condition in Firebase Firstore. I'm using Vue:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  firestore: {
    Words: db.collection("Words").where("incomplete", "==", true).limit(this.page)
  },
}
```

This does not work. I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'page' of undefined
```

I've tried `firebase.page`, also simply `page`, I can't work out how to use that variable in this way. Does anyone know how?

Comment: What do you mean by "This does not work"? What do you get?

Comment: @l1b3rty, sorry, I should have specified. I get ``Cannot read property 'page' of undefined``

Answer (score 1):

The issue relates to the definition of "this" outside the context of a function. I don't use vuefire, but it looks like from the [docs](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuefire.html#bind) that the firestore prop may also be defined as a function, analogous to data(). Providing a functional context for `this`...

```
data() {
  return {
    Words: [],
    page: 1,
  }
},
methods: {
},
firestore() {
  return {
    Words: db.collection("Words").where("incomplete", "==", true).limit(this.page),
  }
},
```

Also note (another learning from perusing vuefire docs), that in order to get `Words` bound to the instance, the property must appear in both the `data()` and `firestore()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with Firestore but with the fact that `this` is not accessible within your custom $option `firestore`.

Try this:

```
methods: {
  firestore() {
    return db.collection("Words").where("incomplete", "==", true).limit(this.page).get()
  }
},
```

And note that this will return a Promise that you will have to handle accordingly